# How to integrate the ace-plugin in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ace-plugin

I would like to use the `ace-plugin` to access the Java files in Ionic (v1). I have added the plugin this way: `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-ace`. But how can I use Ace?

Here is my controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        $scope.a = 'a';
        // Vary the string based on the current platform
        var className = ace.valueOn({
            android: "ForAce"
            , ios: "MyAlgorithm"
        });
        // Create an instance of the native class
        var obj = new ace.NativeObject(className);
        $scope.my_var = obj.invoke("foo");

    });
```

After running `ionic serve --lab` the browser console shows the following error: `error:ReferenceError: ace is not defined`. Do I need to inject the Ace plugin somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Cordova plugins in a browser, you will need to use an emulator or a physical device. The [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/ace) also mentions that you should run it on iOS and Android, because those are the only platforms supported at this moment.

Comment: I have tested on a real device. the same problem.